# Redeclared defined above without usage (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pycharm

Below is my python script. I don't understand why the code cannot be processed with the error statement that the code below the else condition has a syntax error and PyCharm claims that I have "Redeclared 'pi0_t' defined above without usage" with the last line of code.

```
p=0.78
q=0.99
r=1
R=2.3
d=0.65
e=0.1
n=1.5
k=2.7

p1s_bar= 1/((1-e)* (1+ p* (R-1)/((1-p)* q* r)))
p1lt_bar= 1/(1+ p* (d*R- 1)/((1- p)* d* q* r))
chi_s_floor= k/(p1lt_bar* q* r)/ (k/(p1lt_bar* q* r)+ n/(1- (1- e)* p1lt_bar))
chi_s_bar= k/(p1s_bar* q* r)/ (k/(p1s_bar* q* r)+ n/(1- (1- e)* p1s_bar))

chi_s_data= np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)
pi0_s_data= []
pi0_t_data= []
agg_data= []
for chi_s in chi_s_data:
    if chi_s< chi_s_floor:
        pi0_s= n* p* ((R - (1-e)*p1lt_bar)/(1-(1-e)*p1lt_bar))
        pi0_t= p* (d* R*(n+k) - k) + (1-p)*(d*q*r*(n+k)-k)
    elif chi_s>= chi_s_floor and chi_s<= chi_s_bar:
        pi0_s= n* p* R+ (p* k / q*r) * (1-e) * (R- 1)* (1- chi_s)/chi_s
        pi0_t= n* p* d* R+ (1- p)* (d*q*r*n+ (d*(1- e)* q* r- 1)* k+ d* q* r* n* chi_s* q* r/(1- chi_s)
    else:
        pi0_s= n* p* (R - (1-e)* p1lt_bar) / (1 - (1 - e) * p1lt_bar)
        pi0_t= p* (d* R * ( n + k ) - k) + (1-p) * (d* q* r* (n + k) - k)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define pi0_t in the elif statement you are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the line. Change it to

```
pi0_t= n* p* d* R+ (1- p)* (d*q*r*n+ (d*(1- e)* q* r- 1)* k+ d* q* r* n* chi_s* q* r/(1- chi_s))
```

Comment: Please read [answer], and do not attempt to answer questions that are caused by a typo.